# Vertical space in theorem environment closed by an equation containing fractions

Tags: spacing, theorems, amsart

With the amsart document class, if a theorem ends with an equation containing fractions, then the vertical spacing between the theorem and the next line seems too small.

Here is  a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
The following equation holds:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{t} X \wedge \partial_{t} Y_{1} \wedge \dotsb \wedge \partial_{t} Y_{n} \wedge Z_{1} \wedge \dotsb \wedge Z_{n} =0 \,.
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

The proof of the theorem above is straightforward.

\vspace{20mm}
\begin{theorem}
The following equation holds:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial X}{\partial t} \wedge \frac{\partial Y_{1}}{\partial t} \wedge \dotsb \wedge \frac{\partial Y_{n}}{\partial t} \wedge Z_{1} \wedge \dotsb \wedge Z_{n} =0 \,.
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

The proof of the theorem above is straightforward.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can add `\medskip` right after `\end{theorem}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's essentially wanted.

If you add `\showoutput`, you will find, before the first display

```latex
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 4.89998 plus 4.89998
...\glue(\baselineskip) 2.66669
```

and after it

```latex
...\glue(\belowdisplayskip) 4.89998 plus 4.89998
...\glue -4.89998 plus -4.89998
...\glue 4.89998 plus 4.89998
...\glue -7.89998 plus -4.89998
...\penalty -51
...\glue 3.0
...\glue 4.89998 plus 4.89998
...\glue -4.89998 plus -4.89998
...\glue 7.0 plus 2.79996 minus 2.79996
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 2.66669
```

Before the second display you have

```latex
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 4.89998 plus 4.89998
...\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
```

Here `\lineskip` is used because the line with the fractions is too high. After the display

```latex
...\glue(\belowdisplayskip) 4.89998 plus 4.89998
...\glue -4.89998 plus -4.89998
...\glue 4.89998 plus 4.89998
...\glue -8.89998 plus -4.89998
...\penalty -51
...\glue 4.0
...\glue 4.89998 plus 4.89998
...\glue -4.89998 plus -4.89998
...\glue 7.0 plus 2.79996 minus 2.79996
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0
...\glue(\lineskip) 1.0
```

and, again, the interline space is `\lineskip`.

This would be less noticeable in `article`, because `amsart` sets `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` to `5pt plus 5pt` instead of `10pt plus 2pt minus 5pt`.

Theorems are not involved in the problem. You get essentially the same with

```latex
The following equation holds:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{t} X \wedge \partial_{t} Y_{1} \wedge \dots \wedge
\partial_{t} Y_{n} \wedge Z_{1} \wedge \dotsb \wedge Z_{n} =0 \,.
\end{equation}
The proof of the theorem above is straightforward.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial X}{\partial t} \wedge \frac{\partial Y_{1}}{\partial t}
\wedge \dots \wedge \frac{\partial Y_{n}}{\partial t} \wedge Z_{1}
\wedge \dots \wedge Z_{n} =0 \,.
\end{equation}
The proof of the theorem above is straightforward.
```

The only difference is the management of space after the theorem.

You can “fix” by adding `\vspace{1.66667pt}` (or any other value you deem sensible) in the equation with fractions.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newcommand{\fixspace}[1]{%
  \setlength{\lineskip}{#1}%
  \vspace{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
The following equation holds:
\begin{equation}
\partial_{t} X \wedge \partial_{t} Y_{1} \wedge \dotsb \wedge \partial_{t} Y_{n} \wedge Z_{1} \wedge \dotsb \wedge Z_{n} =0 \,.
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

The proof of the theorem above is straightforward.

\begin{theorem}
The following equation holds:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial X}{\partial t} \wedge \frac{\partial Y_{1}}{\partial t} \wedge \dotsb \wedge \frac{\partial Y_{n}}{\partial t} \wedge Z_{1} \wedge \dotsb \wedge Z_{n} =0 \,.
\fixspace{1.66667pt}
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

The proof of the theorem above is straightforward.
\end{document}
```

[image]